# animate duration altering while using parameters

Tags: jquery

The following code animation runs infinitely and runs perfectly every time:

```
function func(){
    $('.one').animate({width:'100%'},5000,function(){
        $('.two').animate({width: '100%'},1000,function(){
            $('div').width('0px');
            func();
        });
    });
}
func();
```

But now I wanted to use parameters for `func()` like this:

```
function func(one,two){
    $('.one').animate({width:'100%'},one,function(){
        $('.two').animate({width: '100%'},two,function(){
            $('div').width('0px');
            func();
        });
    });
}
func(5000,1000);
```

But this time animation duration is very faster (see from next time of animation).

[Demo without parameters](http://jsfiddle.net/9j69kz39/) and [demo with parameters](http://jsfiddle.net/9j69kz39/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing in any values when calling `func();` within your `$('.two').animate()` function. By default, jQuery handles `undefined` animations for you by defaulting them to `400` - this is why the animation gets faster.

Change:

```
$('.two').animate({width: '100%'},two,function(){
    $('div').width('0px');
    func();
});
```

To:

```
$('.two').animate({width: '100%'},two,function(){
    $('div').width('0px');
    func(one, two);
});
```

Comment: could you please check this demo I've some problem with setInterval... http://jsfiddle.net/9j69kz39/3/  the first red div is permanently staying there..

Comment: @C-linkNepal you need to stop the `'.one'` animation. For some reason it's still continuing after the animation completes. You can do this by adding `$('.one').stop(true);` before your `$('div').width()` call.

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/9j69kz39/2/

Call func with the same parameters:

```
 func(one, two);
```